# regex to replace the last digit with a hyphen and a digit

Tags: regex, oracle

Is there a way to replace the last digit with a hyphen and a digit.

```
original            needs to be replaced with
file01              file01-01
file02              file02-02
```

With AmarGhosh I solved this

```
with names as
(
select '/file01/some/file01' name from dual
union all
select '/file02/another/file02' name from dual
)
select name,regexp_replace(name, '^/file0([1-9]+)','/file0\1-\1') new

NAME                      NEW
------------------------- -------------------------
/file01/some/file01       /file01-1/some/file01
/file02/another/file02    /file02-2/another/file02
```

Thanks
Thanks

Comment: See my update. Do you want them to be `file02-02` or `file02-2`; what if there is `file123`?

Comment: There is no file123 just file01 and file02

Comment: that's an example. What do you expect the code to do? what about `file12`, or `foo1234`? Your samples have both `/file02-2` and `file02-02`. Normally, you want your code to work correctly for as much input as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `^/file0([12])/` with `/file0\1-\1/`

Update: for any number of digits following file:

Replace `^/file([0-9]+)/` with `/file\1-\1/`

Update-2: for any number of `/file-01`

Replace `/file([0-9]+)` with `/file\1-\1`

The `^` matches the beginning of a line and hence your regex doesn't match the second `file01` - just get rid of it.

Comment: though from the example, I think the parens should go around the 0 as well:

file(0[12])

Comment: Sorry i had to rephrase the question i want the second row to be /file02/another/file02 /file02-2/another/file02